# Does Karl Pearson correlation indicate linear relationship between two variables?

Tags: correlation, interpretation, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

Wikipedia and literature do not seem to convey correct interpretation of Karl Pearson correlation. Also, some of the authors interpret it as a linear correlation or association. To me it simply tells direction and extent of relation between two variables.

Answer (score 2):

The Pearson correlation coefficient does indeed quantify the **linear relationship** between two variables.

Have a look at one of the many mathematical formulas to compute it, based on a sample of data from two variables $X$ and $Y$:

> [image: Pearson correlation coefficient]

I like to read this loosely in terms of variance (or *spread* across each variable). It is asking, how do $x$ and $y$ scale together? This is the covariance, top part of the fraction. This is scaled by the product of their individual standard deviations, like **normalizing the covariance by the magnitude of the individual variations** $\rightarrow$ bringing the final value into the range $[-1, +1]$.

The [**geometric interpretation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Geometric_interpretation) is also quite intuitive and worth reading.

You could also notice the power of the values. The numerator has $x^1 * y^1$ (so a like a squared term), and the denominator multiplied **two** terms that are each the square root of a squared term, also meaning $x^1 * y^1$. So the final dimensionality is a linear value, as we divide one *squared terms* by another. *(This naïve argument of course neglects the units of $x$ and $y$.)*

---

Here is a nice comparison of many values to gain an intuition - try imagining the linear line of best fit through each of these sets of points, and then how far away the points are from that line. The further away they are, the larger the value of the Pearson correlation coefficient $\rho$. As with normally regression, the sign of the gradient also gives a sign the $\rho$:

[image]
[Image source](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/pearson-correlation-coefficient/)

What value do you think the Pearson Correlation would be for a group of points almost all lying on a vertical line parallel to the y-axis?  :)

[**Compare correlation to regression here**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32464/how-does-the-correlation-coefficient-differ-from-regression-slope).

Comment: scaled by and normalizing - do indicate  meaning of each term separately. How does this process help produce a "linear" relationship ?

Comment: r-coefficient and sample correlation - r(x,y) are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says - KP correlation reflects the strength and direction of a linear relationship (top row), but not the slope of that relationship (middle), nor many aspects of nonlinear relationships (bottom). However, it may be noted Pearson R - the bi-variate correlation (the product-moment correlation coefficient) formula computes variance-covariance.And deducts common-variance from total variance in the numerator.It(total variance) takes care of  curvilinear relation as well along with linear relation between two series(variables). Pearson R simply computes straight line moments in two series under the assumption: Y = a + bX. Further, Pearson R-square helps us to know whether there is straight line (linear)relationship.

Comment: How do you figure that Pearson correlation considers curvature?

Comment: The  r-formulas remove common variance by introducing interaction term for X and Y.

Comment: Do you mean the covariance?

Comment: If we are working with raw scores, expectected (common )variance  wlll be X-bar ×Y-bar

Comment: What does that have to do with curvature?

Comment: sorry, you seem to misinterpret the answer!

Comment: Could you then elaborate on your comment about curvilinear relations?

Comment: In that sense, no, Pearson correlation need not imply a linear relationship between the variables. What do you want to say in your Answer ?

Comment: My answer addresses why Pearson correlation need not imply a linear relationship. What are you trying to say with yours? It sure seems like you’re saying that Pearson correlation considers curves, which is only true in a limited sense (such as I discuss in my answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144552/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

Pearson correlation does measure the strength of the linear relationship between two variables, and other answers address this well. However, a high magnitude of Pearson correlation does not imply a linear relationship. For instance, for positive $X$, $X$ and $X^2$ will have a reasonably strong Pearson correlation, yet the relationship is not linear.

The exception would be if the Pearson correlation is $\pm 1$, which indicates a perfect linear relationship.

In that sense, no, Pearson correlation need not imply a linear relationship between the variables.